# How to generate one string/Hash from two string in flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a Library in Dart to generate one string or hash from 2 different String despite the order of their occurrence.
Example:

```
String first = "xyz";
String second = "abcd"; 

String generated1 = genrateString(first,second);
String generated2 = genrateString(second, first);
AssertTrue(generated1 == generated2)
```

`generated1` And `generated2` should be an identical string string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try sorting them into alphabetical order then using the `hashcode`. (Note that this hash is an `int`).

```
int generateHash(String s1, String s2) =>
    (<String>[s1, s2]..sort()).join().hashCode;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can use `String.compareTo` and MD5 to make simple one (hash collision will still exist).

**Steps**:

1. uses `String.compareTo` to check two input strings
2. if `compreTo` returns `>0`, then uses MD5 to get the hash value for `"$s1${s1.length}$s2${s2.length}"`, otherwise, uses `"$s2${s2.length}$s1${s1.length}"`. Please see first two test cases in the snippet  to see why adding `String.length` into the calculation.

**Snippet**:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:crypto/crypto.dart';

String genHash(String s1, String s2) {
  if (s1.compareTo(s2) > 0) return md5.convert(utf8.encode("$s1${s1.length}$s2${s2.length}")).toString();
  else return md5.convert(utf8.encode("$s2${s2.length}$s1${s1.length}")).toString();
}
void main() {
  String s1 = '11';
  String s2 = '12';
  print(genHash(s1, s2));
  print(genHash(s2, s1));
  assert(genHash(s1, s2) == genHash(s2, s1));
  String s3 = '1';
  String s4 = '121';
  print(genHash(s3, s4));
  print(genHash(s4, s3));
  assert(genHash(s3, s4) == genHash(s4, s3) && genHash(s4, s3) != genHash(s2, s1));
  s1 = '1234';
  s2 = '123';
  print(genHash(s1, s2));
  print(genHash(s2, s1));
  assert(genHash(s1, s2) == genHash(s2, s1));
  s1 = '123';
  s2 = '123';
  print(genHash(s1, s2));
  print(genHash(s2, s1));
  assert(genHash(s1, s2) == genHash(s2, s1));
  s1 = '1';
  s2 = '2';
  print(genHash(s1, s2));
  print(genHash(s2, s1));
  assert(genHash(s1, s2) == genHash(s2, s1));
  s1 = '';
  s2 = '';
  print(genHash(s1, s2));
  print(genHash(s2, s1));
  assert(genHash(s1, s2) == genHash(s2, s1));
  s1 = ' ';
  s2 = '';
  print(genHash(s1, s2));
  print(genHash(s2, s1));
  assert(genHash(s1, s2) == genHash(s2, s1));
}
```